# Reverse animation for Google Map marker removal?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know I can animate the "adding" of a marker on a google map, a la https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#MarkerAnimations

Is there anyway I can do the reverse animation for removing the marker from the map? I'd like it to fly back up to the top of the map on marker removal... is that possible?

Here's my remove code so far (just removes it from the map, no animation):

```
// TODO figure out if there is a way to animate this removal, like the add
$.contextualMap.prototype.removeMarker = function(m) {
  m.mapMarker.setMap(null);
  m.mapMarker = null;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible via the standard [google.maps.Animation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Animation) class, as there are only 2 supported animations (BOUNCE and DROP). You will probabl have to make your own animation using normal javascript and moving the marker on the map.... Don't forget to switch off the shadow or handle it specially...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [google.maps.Animation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Animation) does not support reverse animation of droping, you need to write your own script for animating the marker.

You could write something like this:

```
function removeMarkerWithAnimation(map, marker){
    (function animationStep(){
        //Converting GPS to World Coordinates
        var newPosition = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());

        //Moving 10px to up
        newPosition.y -= 10 / (1 << map.getZoom()); 

        //Converting World Coordinates to GPS 
        newPosition = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(newPosition);
        //updating maker's position
        marker.setPosition( newPosition );
        //Checking whether marker is out of bounds
        if( map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat() < newPosition.lat() ){
            marker.setMap(null);
        }else{
            //Repeating animation step
            setTimeout(animationStep,10);
        }
    })();
}
```

Here is [**DEMO:**](http://jsfiddle.net/bMsTp/)

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a good starting point, and exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @neezer For demonstration purposes, I have used 'linear' easing, but for more realistic animation, probably you need to change `newPosition.y` parameter by using another easing function.

Comment: Would you please update your fiddle link? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

My idea:

1. create an animated GIF of a flying marker pin, which then fades away.
2. on the marker delete event, swap `icon` to show the GIF
3. Since you created the GIF, you should know the animation time length. Then, setTimeout with this value to call setMap(null)

It might be preventing event propagation, which is one of many possible drawbacks.